# Leetcode problem 100, understanding TreeNode

Tags: python, tree

I didn't know where to post this question, but stackoverflow has been helpful before, so I am going to post my question here.

This question is related to Leetcode problem number 100 (Same Tree) and my question is "how do TreeNode" actually work?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

The first test case of the problem has two trees:

```
q = [1,2,3]
p = [1,2,3]
```

You're supposed to return `True` if the trees are the same and `False` otherwise.

I would have thought this would've solved that specific test case:

```
return q.val == p.val and q.left == p.left and q.right == p.right
```

but instead of getting output `True`, I get `False`??

For science I tried just `return q.val`, expecting the output to be `1`, but instead I got output `True`?

I simply don't understand how these trees work. I've also tried defining the class TreeNode in a Jupyter Notebook and defined two trees:

```
q = TreeNode()
q.val = 1
q.left = 2
q.right = 3
```

I did the same for p and ran:

```
q.val == p.val and q.left == p.left and q.right == p.right
```

which did output `True`.

What am I missing? What is it, that I am not understanding?

Comment: Did you saw this video solving and explaining it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRbbcKXCxOw

Comment: Yes I've seen that exact video and multiple other videos, but it hasn't made me understand how return q.val has output True and not 1?

Comment: Post all your code pls. Because following your class and q.val output is 1

Comment: If I implement the class TreeNode in a Jupyter Notebook, it works as expected, but if I do return q.val in the LeetCode problem it tells me that my output was True and not 1 for this specific testcase.

Comment: then print(q.val) if you want to check it

Comment: Thanks, this along with joe-tripodis answer did help me understand what I couldn't before. Much appreciated! The solution expecting a bool value and q.left being a treenode itself and not a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree node has a value and two child nodes (Left and Right). Left references the node to the 'Left', and right references the node to the 'Right'.

If these Trees were created separately than the left and right children would be different objects and therefore they are not the same. The comparison should look like:

> q.val == p.val and q.left.val == p.left.val and q.right.val == p.right.val

Also, in the case of returning True instead of 1, you should post your code. If you are returning directly to LeetCode, then LeetCode is probably expecting a Boolean value to be returned, which means a 1 will be interpreted as True.